# Do I need to setup Whitenoise if Deploying with django-heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

The Heroku documentation says:

> The django-heroku package automatically configures your Django
>   application to work on Heroku. It is compatible with Django 2.0
>   applications.
>
> It provides many niceties, including the reading of DATABASE_URL,
>   logging configuration, a Heroku CI–compatible TestRunner, and
>   automatically configures ‘staticfiles’ to “just work”.

However, I saw other sources where they recommend setting up whitenoise for handling static files. Do I need whitenois if I setup django-heroku? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't 'need' to use WhiteNoise. You can always use a dedicated cloud service/CDN by updating STATICFILES_STORAGE by [serving static files from a cloud service or CDN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/#staticfiles-from-cdn). This may be sounding like a good idea where you get hundreds of thousands of HTTP requests to your project every hour, but we may need to be aware of premature optimisation. Hence comes the easy lightweight solution of WhiteNoise.

Serving server files are extremely efficient with [WhiteNoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) and it's faster and easily blends with the default settings of your project.